# Determine the highest normal form

Tags: database, normalization

I really have no clue how to figure this out. I've read through all the normal forms, but still have trouble understanding it. I hope someone can help me understand it.

Relation schema is R(A,B,C,D,E,F) with (A -> BCD, BC -> DE, B -> D, D -> A).

What is the highest normal form and why?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If A -> BCD and D -> A, surely you've got a recursive relationship?

Comment: @Mark Bannister... The FD `A -> BCD` may be decomposed using [Armstrong's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong's_axioms) into `A -> B`, `A -> C` and `A -> D`. Then we have FD's: `A -> D` and `D -> A` which is just a strict 1 to 1 relationship. The "interesting" FD's are those with multiple attributes on the left hand side (eg. BC -> DE).

Comment: @Roger Pate: thanks for letting me know, I was not aware of that fact.

Answer (score 2):

The highest Normal form is 1NF here, because there are total 3 candidate keys which are AF,DF,BF. So from the given FD set there is partial FD exist, and as per rule , Partial FDs are not allowed in the 2NF. so highest Normal Form is 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the highest Normal Form you may achieve here would be 3NF or BCNF.
I say this is because:

- 1NF requires the elimination of repeating groups and attributes are atomic. You do not have any repeating groups so
  the requirements for 1NF have been met by default.
- 2NF and 3NF deal with how relations are constructed with respect to [Functional Dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency).
  I see you have the following Functional Dependencies described: (A -> BCD, BC -> DE, B -> D, D -> A). Given these,
  you may structrue relations into 2NF, 3NF and possibly BCNF.
- 4NF and above deal with multi-valued facts. You have not described any of these so it is reasonable
  to presume there are none. Some may argue that any BCNF relation where no multi-valued facts
  exist is also in 4NF - I don't want to get into that one because it just boils down to a "glass half full/empty"
  type of arguement.

I have not taken the time to sort out all of the FD's (it is your homework after all), but I would pay close attention
to the FD's: `BC -> D`, `D -> A` and `A -> B`.

The difference between 3NF and BCNF is a bit subtle. This [slide show](http://www.vacic.org/lib/sql/notes/normal.pdf) and [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCNF) 
should help sort it out.

Answer (score -1):

The highest Normal form is 1NF here

Because there are total 3 candidate keys which are AF,DF,BF.

So from the given FD set there is partial FD exist, and as per rule , Partial FDs are not allowed in the 2NF. so highest Normal Form is 1NF.

Answer (score -2):

F doesn't appear anywhere.

There are two possibilities.  Either that's the point of the exercise, or the exercise is flawed.

Comment: Third possibility: `F` is a stand-alone attribute not involved in any functional dependency.